# Probability that a random matrix in $\mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times m}$ is not onto

Tags: probability, matrices

I am struggling to get any starting idea on how to show that given prime $q$, and integers $n,m$ such that $n<m$ that the probability that $A\mathbb{Z}_q^m \neq \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ given $A$ is chosen from the uniform distribution on $\mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times m}$ is less than $\dfrac{1}{q^{m-n}}$.

What will be the starting idea to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is not onto if and only if its image $A\mathbb Z_q^m$ is a subspace of $\mathbb Z_q^n$ with codimension $\geq 1$, which occurs if and only if the orthogonal complement of this subspace has dimension $\geq 1$, which is equivalent to the existence of a non-zero row vector $v\in\mathbb Z_q^n$ such that $vA=0$. By the union bound,
$$
\mathbb P(\exists \textrm{ non-zero }v\in\mathbb Z_q^n\colon vA=0)\leq \sum_{v\in \mathbb Z_q^n\setminus (0,\ldots,0)}\mathbb P(vA=0)\qquad (\star).
$$
Let $A_1,\ldots,A_m\in\mathbb Z_q^n$ denote the columns of $A$, and note that these are independent. Then for any non-zero $v\in\mathbb Z_q^n$ we have that
$$
\mathbb P(vA=0)=\mathbb P(v\cdot A_1=\cdots=v\cdot A_m=0)=\mathbb P(v\cdot A_1=0)^m=q^{-m},
$$
by independence and the observation that $$\mathbb P(v\cdot A_1=0)=\mathbb P(A_1\in \langle v\rangle^{\perp})=\frac{1}{q}$$
for every non-zero $v$ (since the the orthogonal complement of $\langle v\rangle$ is a subspace of dimension $n-1$).

Returning to $(\star)$ it follows that
$$
\mathbb P(\exists \textrm{ non-zero }v\in\mathbb Z_q^n\colon vA=0)\leq (|\mathbb Z_q^n|-1)q^{-m}<q^{n-m},
$$
as desired.